# Spring environment, should I still use Hystrix in a new project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

Seems that [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) is near end of life and that Netflix stack is now a bit deprecated.

We're building a stack for a brand new project and we need a *circuit breaker*, our default choice would have been Hystrix as it is well known and appreciated by the team.

Today Hystrix is fully integrated in Spring Cloud, is there any plan to remove it soon?

Comment: Resilience4j is good option. It's also integrated with Spring boot nicely. Here is the link of example source code - https://github.com/greenlearner01/resilience4j

Comment: Hystrix won't receive any updates as it's now switched to maintenance-only mode. Use Resiliense4j instead

Answer (score 7):

[Spring Cloud Circuit breaker](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker) provides an abstraction across different circuit breaker implementations. It provides a consistent API to use in your applications allowing you the developer to choose the circuit breaker implementation that best fits your needs for your app.

Supported Implementations

- Netfix Hystrix
- Resilience4J
- Sentinel
- Spring Retry

The main benefit of using this is you have option to choose different circuit breaker libraries. Migration from one to other pain point is less.

There is nice documentation and sample code on [official website](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker)

Answer (score 5):

Definitely not. Spring Cloud Hystrix is in [maintenance mode](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now) and will not be available any more starting from the 2020.0.0 release train (support removed with [this commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/48e1618cddfacbbaee2f004416ab010a239c0e2c)). Resilience4J is a good replacement.

Answer (score 4):

[Resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/) is the da circuit-breaker inspired by Hystrix (from Netflix).
You can read more about the project on their webpage or [github](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j), but in short:

> Resilience4j is a lightweight, easy-to-use fault tolerance library inspired by
>   Netflix Hystrix, but designed for Java 8 and functional programming.

And they have a [getting-started](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-6) for spring-cloud as well =)

Edit: rewrote first sentence not to mention it is from Netflix because I am not sure =)

Comment: Is reslience4j by Netflix?? Any ref for this?

Comment: didn't know it was a netflix project !

Comment: On a first glance, I would say yes... but I might update the answer as soon as I find a ref/source. But you can clearly see on Hystrix github page that they are using and recommending `resilience4j` for new projects.

Comment: Hystrix is there since very long time and inspired many circuit breaker libraries. Resilience4j is one of them with many improvement and new features.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up... updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix is not compatible with SpringBoot Greenwich RS6 onwards. Filters and fallback methods are deprecated and do not work anymore. Definitely Hystrix is not the option.