# Why @EnableCircuitBreaker is deprecated for Springboot version 2.5.12 and suggest a replacement

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have upgraded my SpringBoot project to 2.5.12 and the annotation `@EnableCircuitBreaker` is Deprecated. Is there a suitable replacement for that annotation?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864240/spring-env-should-i-still-use-hystrix-on-new-project)

Answer (score 1):

- Resilience4j is a new option for Spring developers to implement the circuit breaker pattern.
- Resilience4j comes with other features like Rate Limiter, Retry and Bulkhead along with Circuit Breaker pattern.
- Resilience4j works well with spring boot and using micrometer libraries, it can emit metrics for monitoring.
- There is no replacement introduced by Spring for Hystrix Dashboard so users need to use prometheus or NewRelic for monitoring.